# Is it possible to use a SharePoint List to display content dynamically added by JS without saving it to the List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I want to display a list in SharePoint Online in my Add-In using JavaScript, but if possible use all the features a stock List offers, like sorting and filtering (especially those two).

Therfore I was wondering whether it is possible to use a normal SharePoint List to display my content (e.g. a list of certain users, sites...) without actually saving the entries to the SPList.

Do you know a way to achieve this, or is it at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a spfx webpart where you load the information to the webpart using lets say the REST api or CSOM. And then use the built in function for filtering in the Office UI fabric components or if you build your own filtering.

As @Derek Gusoff is mentioning in the comment below, you can also use the ui fabric without the spfx model. Many of the components are really useful in other applications. Lets say that you are building a providerhosted addin and want to use the same design language. Well why not use Office-UI-Fabric.

See a demo of the DetailsList component here: [DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist#Variants)

Comment: Good answer, I would add that you can also use Office Fabric separate from spfx in  classic SharePoint.

Comment: Thank you, updated my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly easier approach (if you are familiar with search templates and don't have any inhouse devs to create the web part) could be to customize an item template to show the list content and add the addition info on the fly using basic html and js